# Clock Divider for 50MHz to 1MHz - Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have written the code for SPI Master and I want the output SPI frequency to be 1MHz.

But, when I run the behaviroal simulation, I don't get a 1MHz spi_sclk. Any suggestions what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
 module spi_master(
    input wire clk,
    input wire reset,

    input wire [15:0] datain,

    output wire spi_cs_l,
    output wire spi_sclk,
    output wire spi_data,
    output wire [4:0] counter
);

reg [15:0] MOSI;
reg [4:0] count;
reg cs_l;
reg sclk = 1'b0;
reg [2:0] state;

reg [4:0] clk_counter = 0;

// SPI Output Clock frequency = 1MHz

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (clk_counter == 24) begin
        clk_counter <= 0;
        sclk <= ~sclk;
    end
    else begin
        clk_counter <= clk_counter + 1'd1;
    end
end

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
        MOSI <= 16'b0;
        count <= 5'd16;
        cs_l <= 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
        case (state)
        0:begin
            cs_l <= 1'b1;
            state <= 1;
        end
        1:begin
            cs_l <= 1'b0;
            MOSI <= datain[count-1];
            count <= count-1;
            state <= 2;
        end
        2:begin
            if(count > 0) begin
                state <= 1;
            end
            else begin
                count <= 16;
                state <= 0;
            end
        end
        default:state<=0;
        endcase
    end
end

assign spi_cs_l = cs_l;
assign spi_sclk = sclk;
assign spi_data = MOSI;
assign counter = count;

endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module spi_master_tb;

// Inputs

reg clk;
reg reset;
reg [15:0] datain;

// Outputs

wire spi_cs_l;
wire spi_sclk;
wire spi_data;
wire [4:0] counter;


spi_master dut(
    .clk(clk),
    .reset(reset),
    .counter(counter),
    .datain(datain),
    .spi_cs_l(spi_cs_l),
    .spi_sclk(spi_sclk),
    .spi_data(spi_data)
);


initial begin
    clk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    datain = 0;
end

always #5 clk=~clk;

initial begin
    #10 reset = 1'b0;

    #10 datain = 16'hA569;
    #335 datain = 16'h2563;
    #335 datain = 16'h9B63;
    #335 datain = 16'h6A61;

end

endmodule
```

Waveform

[image]

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 100MHz clock

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have also attached the testbench

Comment: How can you get a 100 MHz clock from a 50 MHz clock? You can only make it slower, not faster. How did you determine that the result clock frequency is 100 MHz?

Comment: @mkrieger1 from the waveform

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have attached the waveform

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell the input clock isn't actually 50 MHz but probably 100 MHz (I'm assuming `#5` means 5 ns)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Right! #5 is 5ns

Comment: If I am counting correctly you are doing 100 MHz -> 50 MHz.

Comment: @mkrieger1 From Input clk 50MHz, I am trying to get the output clock to be 1MHz

Comment: @mkrieger1 Or shall I change the input clk parameter to 100mhz?

Comment: No, you should fix the input clock in the testbench, not by changing `sys_clk`. If you want to generate a 50 MHz clock you need to toggle it every 10 ns to get a 20 ns period.

Comment: Aren't you getting any warnings that you have multiple drivers for `spi_sclk`? You are assigning to it both from `spi_sclk <= ~spi_sclk;` and from `assign spi_sclk = sclk;`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Right! I forgot to change it here! I edited my code

Comment: Now you've got the same problem with `sclk`...

Comment: @mkrieger1 shall I change the counter?

Comment: If you want to divide by 50, you can either count to 24 and toggle the output clock if you reach 24, or you can count to 49 and output 1 if the count is smaller than 25 and 0 otherwise. Currently you are doing a mix of both.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for the help! I have edited my code, but, it is now giving 2MHz spi_sclk output frequency.

Comment: Great, you have successfully divided by 50!

Comment: @mkrieger1 But, how can I get 1MHz? Since, right now it is 2MHz

Comment: By using 50 MHz as input, instead of 100 MHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you create [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also your waveform don't include an important signal `clk_counter`.

Try this in your testbench, if it doesn't work you at least have the minimum reproducible example.

I changed the initialization of `clk_counter` and in the increment I simply added `1` instead of `1'b1`, if you wanted to be strict you could add a 5-bit wide 1 (`5'b1`).

```sv
module spi_master(
    input wire clk,
    input wire reset,
    output wire spi_sclk,
);

reg [4:0] clk_counter;

// SPI Output Clock frequency = 1MHz

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(reset) begin
    sclk <= 1'b0;
    clk_counter <= 1;
  end
  else begin
    if (clk_counter == 24) begin
        clk_counter <= 0;
        sclk <= ~sclk;
    end
    else begin
        clk_counter <= clk_counter + 1;
    end
  end
end

assign spi_sclk = sclk;
endmodule
```